# Social Engine - Form Action is not calling method when submitted

Tags: zend-framework, amazon-web-services, routes, socialengine

I am developing a module for social engine 4. In a widget I have a simple form with a textfield and a button to submit the form.

I made a route in manifest.php file

```
 'routes' => array(
'insert_link' => array(
  'type' => 'Zend_Controller_Router_Route_Static',
  'route' => 'profile/',
  'defaults' => array(
    'module' => 'hallive',
    'controller' => 'videocover',
    'action' => 'insertvideocoverlink'
  )
),
```

)

I put this route inside the action of the form:

```
$this->setAction(Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance()->getRouter()->assemble(array(), 'insert_link'));
```

The method **insertvideocoverlink** is called when the button is pressed and everything works fine in localhost but when I use this code in a remote server (amazon web services) it does not work anymore. Why?

Comment: are you using zf2 or zf1? When you use it on remote, does it involve any cross site request?

Comment: just another note, on remote (shared hosts) zf needs htaccess to be set properly

Comment: It does not involve cross site request. I use Social Engine framework. The framework works fine in localhost and in Amazon except the code above that works only in localhost. Social Engine has many routes in its code and everything works fine.

Comment: Actually I do not know that framework, are you getting any error on screen or in the php log? If you set the route manually and type it in the browser ex yousiteonmaazion.com/profile/controlloer/action what do you get?